# JDBC isssues repeated slow pg_catalog queries

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I have a Spring Data application connected to PostgreSQL and I enabled the slow log (statements of 100 ms). I noticed a number of these kinds of queries, a few per second:

```
2022-02-12 15:43:40.247 GMT [29629] LOG:  duration: 130.888 ms
  bind <unnamed>: SELECT * FROM
 (SELECT n.nspname,c.relname,a.attname,a.atttypid,a.attnotnull OR (t.typtype = 'd' AND t.typnotnull)
 AS attnotnull,a.atttypmod,a.attlen,t.typtypmod,row_number()
 OVER (PARTITION BY a.attrelid ORDER BY a.attnum)
 AS attnum, nullif(a.attidentity, '') as attidentity,pg_catalog.pg_get_expr(def.adbin, def.adrelid) AS adsrc,dsc.description,t.typbasetype,t.typtype
  FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
  JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class c ON (c.relnamespace = n.oid)
  JOIN pg_catalog.pg_attribute a ON (a.attrelid=c.oid)
  JOIN pg_catalog.pg_type t ON (a.atttypid = t.oid)
  LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_attrdef def ON (a.attrelid=def.adrelid AND a.attnum = def.adnum)
  LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_description dsc ON (c.oid=dsc.objoid AND a.attnum = dsc.objsubid)
  LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class dc ON (dc.oid=dsc.classoid AND dc.relname='pg_class')
  LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace dn ON (dc.relnamespace=dn.oid AND dn.nspname='pg_catalog')
  WHERE c.relkind in ('r','p','v','f','m') and a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
  AND n.nspname LIKE 'public' AND c.relname LIKE 'assertion') c WHERE true
  ORDER BY nspname,c.relname,attnum
```

This is not a query my code issuesl my guess is that this query is being issued as part of a JDBC result set mapping. But it looks very inefficient running the same query repeatedly.

The `property_assertion` table is one of mine, but this query is issued for a number of tables in addition to this one. So this isn't confined to just one query meaning there's no specific code I snippet I can narrow this down to.

Is it a problem seeing these repeatedly, at 100ms a go? Might it be the result of misconfiguration?

Comment: Your log does not show 1 (correct) query, but shows 1 query + half of another query (from `attidentity,pg_catalog.pg_get_expr.....`)

Comment: Thanks, I've copied the line from the log again and now I believe it's correct. I think I made an error last time in formatting it to line wrap.

Comment: That's a query for table metadata. I'd suspect a client GUI like pgAdmin.

Comment: Yes that's why I'm confused. I'm just using simple JDBC, not browsing or querying metadata. I have a feeling it might be `SimpleJdbcInsert` performing the query to reflect on the table for field names.